# AWS - How to get Cloudfront metrics using Javascript SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to get Cloudfront metrics using the JS SDK for AWS but I am not getting anything back.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I have isolated this **NOT** to be with:

1. Permissions (gave it a full admin account for testing purposes)
2. Region. North Virginia (for CloudFront)
3. Basic params like: StartDate, EndDate, DistributionID

My code is as below (simplified):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
  secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
  apiVersion: '2017-10-25',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

var cloudwatchmetrics = new AWS.CloudWatch();

var cloudFrontParams = {
    "StartTime": 1518867432,
    "EndTime": 1518868032,
    "MetricDataQueries": [
        {
          "Id": "m1",
          "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
              "Dimensions": [
                {
                  "Name": "DistributionId",
                  "Value": "ValueOfDistribution"
                },
                {
                  "Name": "Region",
                  "Value": "Global"
                }
                ],
              "MetricName": "Requests",
              "Namespace": "AWS/CloudFront"
            },
            "Stat": "Sum",
            "Period": 3600
          },
          "ReturnData": true
        }
      ]
};

cloudwatchmetrics.getMetricData(cloudFrontParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

This is what I get back (it's not erroring out):

```
{
  "ResponseMetadata":{
     "RequestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "MetricDataResults":[
     {
        "Id":"m1",
        "Label":"Requests",
        "Timestamps":[
           
        ],
        "Values":[
           
        ],
        "StatusCode":"Complete",
        "Messages":[
           
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the **StartTime**, it was too far back in time. What I have in the post translates to: *Saturday, February 17, 2018*

Hopefully this helps someone someday.